# Intelij IDEA scala test - compilation error, but ok in sbt

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, scalatest

I'm getting following compilation error in Intelij Idea when running scalatests in my play framework application:

> Error:(41, 54) Cannot find an instance of play.api.libs.json.JsObject
>   to WSBody. Define a BodyWritable[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] or
>   extend play.api.libs.ws.ahc.DefaultBodyWritables
>         val response = await(wsClient.url(testUrl).post(data))

Though when running `sbt test` it compiles and runs fine.

I've tried to clear Intelij cache and restart, didn't help.

What can be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by deleting `.idea` folder and re-importing the project.